# How can I skip one line in a txt file

Tags: vba, text, copy, line, skip

[image: line 2 is the new string. line 3 is the one I want to skip\delete. line 3 is the old string]

I have a `txt` file called `inFile`. With VBA, I copy it line by line to a new `tx`t file called `outFile`.

I have an Excel worksheet. In this sheet, I have a string and a number. The number is the line where the new string needs to go in the `txt` called `outFile`.

95% of my code works.

**My problem:** After the code copy the lines from the `txt` called `inFile` to `outFile`, and after I copy the new string from the Excel sheet to the right line.
When I go back to copy the other line from the `txt` called `inFile` to the `txt` called `outFile`.
The code copied the line that I just replaced with the new string.

I'm looking for a way to skip one line while copying the line from `inFile` to `outFile`.

**P.S.**
`cell(f,13)` is where the line number for the new string is placed.
`cell(f,17)` is where the new string should be placed.

```
Sub Update_file()

    Dim FolderName As Double
    Dim data1, data2, IfExist, inFile, outFile As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim LineNumber As Long

    f = 2
    LineNumber = 0

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(f, 2))
        IfExist = "L:\" & Cells(f, 2) & "\COMPANY.bat"
            If Not Dir(IfExist) = "" Then                  
                inFile = "L:\" & Cells(f, 2) & "\COMPANY.bat"
                Open inFile For Input As #1                
                outFile = "L:\" & Cells(f, 2) & "\COMPANY_NEW.bat"
                Open outFile For Output As #2               
                    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(f, 11)) Then                
                        LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
                            If LineNumber = Cells(f, 13) Then
    'aaa:
                                data2 = Cells(f, 17)
                                Print #2, data2
                                LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
                                GoTo bbb
                            Else
                                Do Until EOF(1) Or Cells(f, 13) = LineNumber 
    'bbb:
                                Debug.Print LineNumber
                                Line Input #1, data1
                                data2 = Trim(data1)
                                Print #2, data2
                                LineNumber = LineNumber + 1                            
                                    If LineNumber = Cells(f, 13) Then
                                        GoTo aaa
                                    End If                        
                                Loop                        
                            End If                
                        End If                
                LineNumber = 0
                Close #1
                Close #2                
            Else: MsgBox "äçáøä " & Mid(inFile, 4, 5) & " ìà ÷ééîú"            
            End If    
        f = f + 1    
    Loop    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you always want to write to file #2; either the line from file #1, or the line from Cells(f, 17) if we are at the target line number.

Why not just this then?

```
inFile = "L:\" & Cells(f, 2) & "\COMPANY.bat"
Open inFile For Input As #1

outFile = "L:\" & Cells(f, 2) & "\COMPANY_NEW.bat"
Open outFile For Output As #2

If Not IsEmpty(Cells(f, 11)) Then
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Debug.Print LineNumber
        Line Input #1, data1
        data2 = Trim(data1)

        If LineNumber = Cells(f, 13) Then
            data2 = Cells(f, 17)
        End If

        Print #2, data2
        LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
    Loop
End If

LineNumber = 0

Close #1
Close #2
```